# sample program for "hello world" in COW programming language

Tags: programming-languages

ive been looking on the web for a sample program for "hello world" in COW programming language. unfortunately, i haven't been successful yet. ive seen some but they are different from one another. what would be the right one?

sample program for "hello world" in COW programming language

Comment: Funny, they have a [Fibonacci sequence generator](http://www.bigzaphod.org/cow/), but no Hello World. :o)

Answer (score 6):

It is here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HelloWorldInManyProgrammingLanguages

And it works, too!  Try it here: http://www.frank-buss.de/cow.html